# counting another problem

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to do my homework and it seems really hard. i would like to get checked here and make sure that im on the right track. can anyone help me??

Question: A group of hundred students want to create a committee of twelve which will then select a chairman for the committee.
a) In how many ways can this be accomplished?
b) what if they decide to have two members serve as co-chairs??

Answer a) $P(100,12)= \dfrac{100!}{12!(100-12)!}$;
Answer b) $P(100,12)+ P(12,1)+ P(12,2)$.

since the order matters and repetition is not allowed, i selected 12 from 100 students.

did i do it right??

Comment: Why do you say that order matters? From what you've described, it doesn't sound like it does.

Comment: 1) Order *doesn't* matter. 2) What about selecting the chairman?

Comment: i assumed that order matters and repetition is not allowed...i could be wrong though.

Comment: You lost a set of parentheses.  Presumably you want $(100-12)!$ in the denominator.  You should put parentheses around the whole denominator to make sure people don't read it as $\frac {100!}{12!}\cdot (100-12)!$

Comment: Clearly repetition is not allowed.  Your division by $12!$ says that order does not matter-that you only care about which students are on the committee, not the order they are selected.  +1 for showing your work.

Comment: Let's think about your assumption that order matters: does it make a difference if a specific student is chosen first or last?

Comment: Often the notation for $\dfrac{100!}{12!(100-12)!}$ is $C(100,12)$ rather than $P(100,12)$.  The letters stand for "combination" and "permutation".  What you want here is combintations, since the order doesn't matter.  One also somethimes writes $C(100,12)$ written as $\dbinom{100}{12}$.

Comment: The calculation you give for $P(100, 12)$ uses the formula for $C(100, 12)$. Which one do you mean?

Comment: C(100,12). i am so sorry gentlemen. i was confused as well until now. i meant to say C(100,12). thank you much!!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to a is correct for selecting the committee, but ignores choosing the chairman.  The use of $P(100,12)$ is strange, because the order of the selection does not matter.  Your expression would usually be written $C(100,12)$ or ${100 \choose 12}$ with the value you give $\frac {100!}{12!(100-12)!}$.  I would take $P(100,12)$ to say that order matters and evaluate it as $\frac {100!}{(100-12)!}$.  Now you need to multiply by $C(12,1)={12 \choose 1}$ to pick the chairman.

For b, you should multiply by the number of ways to select the co-chairs.  It seems order does not matter here (it is not a chair and vice-chair, where order would matter).

Comment: i meant to use C(100,12). sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> A group of hundred students want to create a committee of twelve which will then select a chairman for the committee. In how many ways can this be accomplished?

First you're choosing 12 out of 100 people to be on the committee: $\binom{100}{12}$. Then you're choosing one out of that 12 to be the committee head: $\binom{12}{1}$.

> what if they decide to have two members serve as co-chairs??

Same as before, only now instead of choosing a single person for committee head, you're choosing two: $\binom{12}{2}$.

Comment: The two co-chairs in case (b) **replace** (are instead of)  the single chair of case $(a)$.

Comment: oooooohh okay. so then for a) it would just be (12,1)= 12!/(1!(12-1)!)  AND b) 11!/(2!(11-2)!) right??

Comment: No ammie: see the now correct post.

Comment: @ammie I edited. I hadn't realized the co-chairs would replace the single chair, but I corrected accordingly.

Comment: @ammie And don't forget, you need to use the rule of products. So the first problem would be $\binom{100}{12}\binom{12}{1}$.

Comment: @ammie Note this answer gives the number of committees chosen out of the 100 students and the the number of chairs that can be chosen out of *one* of those committees. The way I read your original homework question, you need to combine these in some way to count the number of ways you can choose committees *and* a chair for the committee.

Comment: and for b) i guess i would have to just add (12,2) to a) right??

Comment: For b) you're multiplying $\binom{100}{12}\binom{12}{2}$

Comment: i meant to say that. so sorry. it was my fault

Comment: i am curious why i cant write answer as this: (100,12)+(12,1)+(12,1). dont i have to add??

Comment: @ammie: You would do that if you were choosing $12$ committee members **or** 1 committee head **or** another committee head. But you're choosing $12$ committee members **and** 2 committee heads.

Comment: Zettaseuro you are so helpful!! thank you very much